# Get radio button value from view to controller - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, radio-button

I have searched and searched and have found relevant answers to this question, but I am having an awful time applying to my application. Please forgive me, I am very new.

I am making a simple multiple choice quiz using radio buttons. I can not, for the life of me, get my controller to read the value from the selected radio button in the view. I am also not using a database at all.

Any direction would be so much appreciated! And I've never posted on here, let me know if I need to add anything else.

Thanks again and again for any help!

MODEL:

```
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace CommunityInfo.Models
    {
    public class QuizInfo
    {
        public string Question1 { get; set; }
        public string Question2 { get; set; }
        public string Question3 { get; set; }
        public string Question4 { get; set; }
        public string Question5 { get; set; }
    }
    }
```

VIEW:

```
    @model CommunityInfo.Models.QuizInfo
    @{ Layout = null; }

    <DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center"><h4>Magic Pony Land Trivia!</h4></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div>
                        <label for="q1">When was Magic Pony Sparkle Land founded?</label><br />
                        @Html.RadioButton("Question1", "a") 1 B.C. <br />
                        @Html.RadioButton("Question1", "b") 1900 <br />
                        @Html.RadioButton("Question1", "c") 2018 <br />
                    </div>
                @*<div>
                        <label for="q2">Who is the mayor of Magic Pony Sparkle Land?</label><br />
                        @Html.RadioButton("Question2", "a") Twighlight Sparkle <br />
                        @Html.RadioButton("Question2", "b") Pinkie Pie <br />
                        @Html.RadioButton("Question2", "c") Oprah <br />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="q3">How many magic ponies inhabit Magic Pony Sparkle Land?</label><br />
                        @Html.RadioButton("Question3", "a") 4 <br />
                        @Html.RadioButton("Question3", "b") 999,999,999 <br />
                        @Html.RadioButton("Question3", "c") 500 <br />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="q3">What is the Magic Pony Sparkle Land mascot?</label><br />
                        @Html.RadioButton("Question3", "a") Sparkly Pony (duh) <br />
                        @Html.RadioButton("Question3", "b") Sloth <br />
                        @Html.RadioButton("Question3", "c") Ostrich <br />
                    </div>*@
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

CONTROLLER

```
         using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

          namespace CommunityInfo.Controllers
    {
       public class QuizController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Quiz()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Quiz(string Question1)
    {
        if (Question1 == "a")
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        else
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You view is based on `QuizInfo` which means your POST method parameter must also be `QuizInfo` - `public ViewResult Quiz(QuizInfo model)` and you need to use `<form method="post">` (by default its a Get), or better use `@using (Html.Beg'nForm()) { .... ` to generate the `<form>` element

Comment: Thank you so much! I was working on that for an obscene amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Just missing one thing on your form tag to get the value to post:

```
<form method="post">
```